# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1:war - Could not copy resource

Tags: eclipse, maven, ubuntu

I have a multi-module project that I'm trying to import in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS's Eclipse Juno. (I already have done it successfully on Windows 7).

My project has six modules, the first four modules are successfully imported from the SVN Repository and built with `Maven 3.0.5`, but when I try to build the fifth called `core`, i receive the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1:war (default-war) on project core: Could not copy resource [/opt/workspace/core/target\preassembly]: File /opt/workspace/core/target\preassembly/scripts/Mask.js does not exist -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

As the error says, It looks like that Maven can't find the directory  `/opt/workspace/core/target\preassembly` to copy the file `/opt/workspace/core/target\preassembly/scripts/Mask.js`.

But, this directory actually exists and the file `Mask.js` is in there. What looks strange to me is that backslash `\` after `target` directory instead a common bar `/`. But I have no idea if this is a problem and how to solve it, I spent 2 days researching the Internet but unfortunately I've found nothing.

Here's my maven-war-plugin configuration section of parent project's `pom.xml`, where the backslashes appear

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}\preassembly</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

I've also checked the owner of the directories on Ubuntu, and everything refers to the same owner that worked on the first four modules.

As I said above, the same version of eclipse, svn and maven works great on Windows.

Anyone ever had this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: have you checked your `pom.xml` files for backslashes? It works on Windows because slashes are automatically converted to backslashes by Java/Maven. If you can't find anything, could you provide the `maven-war-plugin` configuration section of the POM file?

Comment: Hi @nif, you're right! My `maven-war-plugin` section of my parent module had those backslashes on directory configuration. The build worked after I replaced all of them with a common slash. Anyway, I'm going to edit my post to provide the requested configuration section. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on angular 8 and updated the code to angular 9 and then during build i got the same issue .For me clean build solved the issue.You can try clean build , hope that will help .